# OR conditional in authentication - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am doing the conditional authentication for the login so the user will redirect to their pages respectively. My code is:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (auth()->user()->department == 'HR' || 'Human Resource' ) {
            return '/hr';

        }
        elseif (auth()->user()->department == 'Accountant' || 'ACC' ) {
            return '/acc';
        }
        else return '/';
    }
```

However, when I run the code, the page is redirected to the wrong page. How to add OR clause to the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This Not Use directly `||`**

```
((auth()->user()->department == 'HR') || (auth()->user()->department == 'Human Resource'))

((auth()->user()->department == 'Accountant') || (auth()->user()->department == 'ACC'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if ((auth()->user()->department == 'HR') || (auth()->user()->department == 'Human Resource')) {
        return '/hr';

    }
    elseif ((auth()->user()->department == 'Accountant') || (auth()->user()->department == 'ACC')) {
        return '/acc';
    }
    else return '/';
}
```